# I can't publish myFlutter app because its saying its in debug mode although I have done all the steps nd generated key

Tags: android, flutter

I have created keystore and and generated my app bundle.
The name of my build file is also app-release.aab but still google saying the the app is in debug mode even though I have done the steps mentioned in googles "Build and release an android app" doc.

Please help

Comment: please go through this https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android for releasing the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you followed those steps to the letter, you have to edit your app-level build,gradle to look something like this and you have the key.properties file under android/.

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```